# syntax error near unexpected token `(' bash

Tags: bash

I have this command that I'm trying to convert to script :

```
wget -nc -P $path -i <(
  wget -qO- $url |
    grep -o "https://www\.lezioni4all\.com/files/[^']*\.pdf")
```

When I run it the output is : `syntax error near unexpected token (`

So I added `\` before parentheses but seems useless, same output :

```
wget -nc -P $path -i <\(
 wget -qO- $url |
  grep -o "https://www\.lezioni4all\.com/files/[^']*\.pdf"\)
```

Comment: "convert to script" -- what kind of script? It sounds like your script starts with `#!/bin/sh`. Don't do that; use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: ...re: whether to switch to zsh, see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: `<(...)` is what's called _process substitution_; it's a feature bash and zsh have, but `sh` does not. Thus, when you run your script with `sh yourscript`, that feature is not available.

Comment: Also consider a guard like `case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "ERROR: This only supports bash" >&2; exit 1;; esac` (suggesting that form so you can change `'')` to something like`''|[123].*)` if you want to only support bash 4.0 or newer in the future).